# The order about the releasing of local var

Tags: objective-c

There are four classes:

```
@implementation AClass

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"a");
}

@end

@implementation BClass

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"b");
}

@end

@implementation CClass

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"c");
}

@end

@implementation DClass

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"d");
}

@end
```

Now do a test:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    AClass *a = [AClass new];
    NSLog(@"1");
    BClass *b = [BClass new];
    NSLog(@"2");
    [CClass new];
    NSLog(@"3");
    [DClass new];
    NSLog(@"4");
}
```

The console printed:

```
1 2 c 3 d 4 b a
```

---

Question:

**Why `c` `d` before than `a` `b` and why `b` before than `a`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c and d don't have variable strong reference, then it will release before a, b( c,d Release after create).
I think `ARC`(Automatic Ref Counting) `insert objc_release` assembly call c,d before a, b.

About b release before a, I think `ARC` will release variable from bottom to top.

You can set breakpoint at `viewDidLoad` function and choose menu `Debug>Debug Workflow>Always show disassembly` to see.

Answer (score 0):

[Automatic Reference Counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting)

ARC automatically adds `retain`/`release` when you compile your code.

In this case, `c` and `d` are released right away since there are no strong pointers to them. `a` and `b` have strong pointers through their variables and the compiler will add a `release` call when those variables go out of scope (at the end of the method). If you use `__weak` for one of the variables, it will be dealloc'd right away.

The order between `a` and `b` being released is an ARC implementation detail and it probably isn't wise to rely on it as Clang makes no guarantees about the order so it can potentially change.